# Python - Custom matplotlib style in .exe built with pyinstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I am building an .exe with pyinstaller which purpose is to automatically build graphs from measurements. 
The use of a custom made plotting style generated warnings during compiling and crashed the .exe.
However, when the "classic" plotting style is used, the exe runs just fine.

My question is the following, can you use a cutom plot style when compiling with pyinstaller and if yes what is the way to do so ?

I am aware that i could change the pyplot parameters in script but this is not what i am looking for.